# Why is this random variable Binomial distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Regarding the following question:

> Find the probability that in a group of 20 individuals, there are at
>   least 3 individuals born in March, given that there is an individual
>   born in March 20.

The solution marks X as the number of individuals born in march and calculates:
$$ P(X\geq3 | X \geq 1) $$

Claiming that X is binomial distributed. But why?
What is the intuition for that? I though that binomial distribution mostly relates to experiments (like flipping a coin until "heads" shows etc), but for some reason this case doesn't look like an experiment or anything similar.

Thanks!

Comment: If $X_i$ is "the i-th person is born in march, then $X=X_1+...+X_{20}$, i.e. a sum of iid Bernoulli r.v.

Comment: There are only two outcomes, "born in March" and "not born in March."  The experiment is to pick a random person, and determine if he was born in March.  We perform the experiment $20$ times.